# xterm -title "test" doesnt work in Ubuntu 8.04

Tags: ubuntu, xterm, ubuntu-8.04

i am trying to set a title ("test") on the window I am opening with xterm (`xterm -title "test"`). It isn't working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You might check that the title isn't being overwritten by something in your .bash or .profile - there exists an escape sequence to set window title which might be embedded in your prompt or something else that is displayed.